# Why is tzinfo-data not recognized in the Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tzinfo

Similar to other queries I found that upon running `rails s` exits the program immediately and says:

```
in 'rescue in create_defaut_data_source': tzinfo-data is not present. Please add gem 'tzinfo-data' to your Gemfile and run bundle install (TZInfo:: DataSourceNotFound)
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFgtf.png)

I ran both `gem install tzinfo` and `gem install tzinfo-data`. When I checked the Gemfile file, the tzinfo-data gem was also present.

Has anyone else had a similar issue?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Include the stuff you've linked to in your question, as text, properly formatted.  Maybe review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi thanks, I'm pretty new to this platform. I'll check out how format properly